# Passing a Tie::IxHash object to the Template module

Tags: perl

I am using Perl v5.18.2.

I want hash elements printed in order with Perl's [`Template`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) module, but the hash seems to be ordered only until it gets passed to `Template`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::IxHash;
use Template;
use Test::More;

tie my %hash, 'Tie::IxHash';
%hash = ('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3);
my %vars = ('hash' => \%hash); 

is_deeply(\[keys $vars{'hash'}], \['one', 'two', 'three'], 'key order');
is_deeply(\[values $vars{'hash'}], \[1, 2, 3], 'value order');

my $t = Template->new(STRICT => 1) || die(Template->error());
my $template = '[% FOREACH k IN hash %][% k.value %][% END %]';
my $output = '';

$t->process(\$template, \%vars, \$output) || die $t->error();

is($output, '123', 'templatized hash order');

done_testing(3);
```

This always fails:

```
ok 1 - key order
ok 2 - value order
not ok 3 - templatized hash order
#   Failed test 'templatized hash order'
#   at t/wtf.t line 18.
#          got: '132'
#     expected: '123'
1..3
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 3.
```

What am I missing here? And how can I preserve hash element order in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tied hash loses its magic when it is passed to Template Toolkit which doesn't use the tied hash, but makes plain copy of it instead.  To get around this, you can just store and pass in your key order and use it to pull out your hash elements in order.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::IxHash;
use Template;
use Test::More;

tie my %hash, 'Tie::IxHash';
%hash = ('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3);
is_deeply([keys %hash], ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'key order');
is_deeply([values %hash], [1, 2, 3], 'value order');
my @key_order = keys %hash;
my %vars = ( 'hash' => \%hash, key_order => \@key_order );

my $t = Template->new(STRICT => 1) || die(Template->error());
my $template = '[% FOREACH k IN key_order %][% hash.$k %][% END %]';
my $output = '';
$t->process(\$template, \%vars, \$output) || die $t->error();
is($output, '123', 'templatized hash order');
done_testing(3);
```

**Output**

```
ok 1 - key order
ok 2 - value order
ok 3 - templatized hash order
1..3
```

Comment: *"It seems that the tied hash loses its magic when it is part of another data structure"* No, it would be fine if a `Tie::IxHash` were the value of an array or hash element. The problem is the way the `Template` module handles the values in the `%vars` parameter: it makes an internal copy of the data and thereby loses any *tie* magic.

Comment: You're welcome. But you've now edited your answer to say the same as my own!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that

When you call the `process` method on the `Template` object, the values that you pass in the `%vars` parameter are *copied* to an ordinary data structure before they are used to build the document

The obvious alternative is to collect the hash keys into an array before calling `process`, and pass that as another element of the `%vars` parameter. This program shows the idea

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Tie::IxHash;
use Template;

tie my %hash, 'Tie::IxHash';
%hash = (one => 1, two => 2, three => 3);


my @keys = keys %hash;
my %vars = (hash => \%hash, keys => \@keys); 

my $t = Template->new(STRICT => 1) or die Template->error;

my $template = <<'END_TEMPLATE';
[% FOREACH k IN keys %][% hash.$k %]
[% END %]
END_TEMPLATE

my $output;
$t->process(\$template, \%vars, \$output) or die $t->error;

print $output;
```

#### output

```
1
2
3
```

Of course this removes much of the point of using `Tie::IxHash` in the first place, and you may well be better off using an ordinary hash with a parallel array of keys